# Cubic spline with "end-only" boundary condition

Tags: interpolation, spline

I'm thinking of applying the cubic spline interpolation to many sets of datapoints. The only knowledge I have is that each set corresponds to a function defined on [0,R] which smoothly decays to 0 at R, and various functions may behave differently near 0. I feel a good boundary condition in this case is to enforce both the first and second derivatives at R to be 0. However, I did a little research and did not find any software/package/library providing this option.

My question is, is this a valid boundary condition? Or is there better choice in this situation?